# Calculating average BPM between 2 'tap' events (maths)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, logic

I am working on a Metronome app and am required to implement a tap to set BPM feature.

I currently am recording the gap in milliseconds between the current tap and the previous tap. Using these numbers I wish to work out the BPM.

Tapping at roughly 130bpm gives me results of around 450ms.

I can't seem to work out the equation to turn 450ms into BPM?

Any help on the logic.

The ms is worked out using:

```
$scope.tapStart = +new Date();

$scope.detectTempoFromTap = function() {
    var now = +new Date();

    console.log(now - $scope.tapStart);

    $scope.tapStart = +new Date();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One second is 1000ms, so in one second you get `(1000/450 =) 2.222...` beats.

In one minute (= 60 seconds) you get `(1000 / 450) * 60 = 133.333...` beats.

Comment: Thanks, couldn't get my head around it but that makes perfect sense.